# What does &hellip mean/do(from Java Generics FAQ)?

Tags: java

I was reading a [Java Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html#Raw%20Types), and came across `&hellip` in various contexts:

```
public interface Action<E extends Exception> { 
  void run() throws E ; 
} 
public final class Executor { 
  public static <E extends Exception> 
    void execute(Action<E> action) throws E {  
      &hellip; 
      action.run(); 
      &hellip; 
  } 
} 
public final class Test { 
  private static class TestAction implements Action<java.io.FileNotFoundException> { 
    public void run() throws java.io.FileNotFoundException { 
      &hellip; 
      throw new java.io.FileNotFoundException() ;  
      &hellip; 
  } 
  public static void main(String[] args) { 
    try {  
      Executor.execute(new TestAction()) ; 
    } catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException f) { &hellip; } 
  } 
}
```

I then found this:

```
class SomeLegacyClass { 
  public void setNames(List c) { &hellip } 
  public List getNames() { &hellip } 
}
final class Test { 
  public static void main(String[] args) { 
    SomeLegacyClass obj = new SomeLegacyClass(); 
    List<String> names = new LinkedList<String>(); 
    &hellip fill list &hellip

    obj.setNames(names);

    names = obj.getNames();    // unchecked warning 
  } 
}
```

After a little more digging, I found another version of the above snippet with `&hellip` replace by `…`; despite a decent amount of googling, I couldn't find out what this actually means.  When I attempted to put it in code, it didn't work, I'm not sure if that's because it's just some sort of commenting shorthand or this is antiquated code.  Could someone please tell me what `&hellip` is/means.

Comment: It's a screw-up, it should have been a HTML entity, `&hellip;`, which is …

Comment: Can you not downvote me, I'm trying to close the question.  I didn't know...

Comment: The was posted a while ago, but given that it's got over 1k views, I guess it's not too localized and should be reopened.  There's already an answer, so not sure what reopening will do, but it seems not be helpful to a lot of people.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

That's an HTML entity; it stands for **H**orizontal [Ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis). It looks like this: *…* (One symbol; not three separate dots)

That means that their HTML is broken.

Comment: Just wow, short, sweet and best answer.